# 2 column layout for Highcharts legend categorized by type - React highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, flexbox, react-highcharts

I want to create a chart where the legend is split into number of columns based on distinct `scenario` from the JSON. The legend items should be categorized under each header, but from what I did, the header always gets prepended to each legend item. Please advice.

This is what I have:

```
    import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";

    import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
    import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
    import HC_more from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
    import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
    import HC_series_label from "highcharts/modules/series-label";
    import HC_boost from "highcharts/modules/boost";
    import { map, slice } from "lodash";

    HC_more(Highcharts);
    HC_exporting(Highcharts);
    HC_series_label(Highcharts);
    HC_boost(Highcharts);

    const App = (props) => {
      const options = {
        colors: [
          "#800000",
          "#9A6324",
          "#808000",
          "#469990",
          "#000075",
          "#e6194b",
          "#f58231",
          "#ffe119",
          "#bfef45",
          "#3cb44b",
          "#42d4f4",
          "#4363d8",
          "#911eb4",
          "#f032e6"
        ],
        chart: {
          zoomType: "x",
          resetZoomButton: {
            position: {
              align: "left", // by default
              verticalAlign: "top", // by default
              x: -10,
              y: 10
            }
          },
          type: "line",
          height: props.height ? props.height : `60%`
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: true,
          chartOptions: {
            xAxis: [
              {
                max: null
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: props.title
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: ""
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: null
          },
          labels: {
            formatter: function () {
              return `${Highcharts.numberFormat(
                this.value / 1,
                props.decimalPlaces,
                "."
              )}`;
            },
            style: {
              fontSize: "13px"
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          itemStyle: {
            fontSize: "15px"
          },
          floating: false,
          itemMarginBottom: 5,
          width: 180,
          itemWidth: 100,
          useHTML: true,
          labelFormatter: function () {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(`data.Series[Number(this.userOptions.id)]`);
            return `<div>${
              data.Series[Number(this.userOptions.id) - 1].scenario
            }<div>${this.name}</div></div>`;
          }
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: data.Dates.map((item) => item.Date),
          labels: {
            style: {
              fontSize: "13px"
            }
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            boostThreshold: 2000,
            label: {
              enabled: false,
              connectorAllowed: false
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormatter: function () {
            return `${Highcharts.numberFormat(
              this.options.y / 1,
              props.decimalPlaces,
              "."
            )}`;
          }
        },
        series: map(slice(data.Series, 0, 15), (item) => {
          return {
            name: item.segment,
            data: item.values,
            type: "line",
            id: item.id.toString()
          };
        })
      };

      return (
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} {...props} />
      );
    };

    export default App;
```

Stackblitz Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-cherry-2qhr6?file=/src/App.js:0-25119
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7owjmq

Expected Output: [image]

Comment: I am afraid that creating this legend is not available using the standard API options, see: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11309. The possible solution to achieve this effect is by creating a custom legend. The example you can find here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32764 Let me know what do you think about it.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel This is what I have - https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-fog-cds4u?file=/src/App.js I created a custom div and appending the new legend into it. However, I think I am missing a small bit when I try to click on the legend as the last one is always toggled. Also if you could help me out on rendering the symbols in the custom legend as well, that would be of great help.

Comment: I see that you opened the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64811381/add-symbol-to-custom-legend-layout-highcharts-react/64820666#64820666, so I assume that your above question is out of date.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes, thats correct as this didnt contain the custom legend layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging more into your requirement I decided that it will be better to position the already existed legend items and create the custom labels name than trying to render them in the custom legend. I added some comments in the code, so I think that everything is clearly explained - in case of any doubts feel free to ask.

Simple JS demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8wnq2y4k/

React version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-djeehw

```
events: {
  render() {
    const chart = this;
    const labelsPos = 450;
    let firstColumnY = 50; // Distance from the chart to the legend
    let secondColumnY = 50; // Distance from the chart to the legend


    chart.legend.allItems.forEach(l => {
      // First column
      if (l.userOptions.scenario === 'Class 1') {
        let group = l.legendGroup;

        group.translate(-chart.plotWidth / 2 + chart.plotLeft + group.getBBox().width, firstColumnY);
        firstColumnY += 23; // Where 23 is a height of the one legend label
      }


      // Second column
      if (l.userOptions.scenario === 'Class 2') {
        let group = l.legendGroup;
        group.translate(chart.plotWidth / 2, secondColumnY);
        secondColumnY += 23; // Where 23 is a height of the one legend label
      }
    });
            
            // Keep labels position responsive by deleting them and render again
    if (chart.firstLabel && chart.secondLabel) {
      chart.firstLabel.destroy();
      chart.secondLabel.destroy();
    }
      chart.firstLabel = chart.renderer.label('Class 1', 0, labelsPos).css({
          'font-size': '22px'
        })
        .add();

      chart.secondLabel = chart.renderer.label('Class 2', chart.plotWidth, labelsPos).css({
          'font-size': '22px'
        })
        .add();
      chart.secondLabel.translate(chart.secondLabel.x - chart.secondLabel.getBBox().width + 10, labelsPos)
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#destroy

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#translate

---

If you want to try to implement the symbols to your custom legend here is a part of the code responsible for it: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/Core/Legend.js#L479

Comment: Thanks so much. I will extend this to accomodate dynamic named columns.